# How to handle response from external API that has multiple content-type

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I have a problem of handling multiple content-type response. The external API that I am calling returns person's info in text/plain and person's image in image/jpg. I want to be able to get both the person's info and person's image and return them to client. An example of the response data is as follow:

```
--myboundary
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 4809

Events[0].Name=John Smith
Events[0].Country=USA
Events[0].Age=32

--myboundary
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 0

6�j4t�h��
```

And since the API is a subscribe/listen type, I want to be able to detect end of stream

I have tried with the following codes, but the output is not correct

```
//Detect whether it is image type
var magic = {
  jpg: 'ffd8ffe0',
  png: '89504e47',
  gif: '47494638'
};

var items = {};
var responseBody = [];

request(http://someurl/api/person)
    .auth(USERNAME, PASSWORD, false)
    .on('response', function(response) {
      console.log('Response: ' + response);
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Error detecting : ' + err);
      self.emit('detect', { status: 'Unable To Detect' }); //emit error to client
    })
    .on('data', function(data) {
        //Check if it is image. If yes, push to responseBody
      var magigNumberInBody = data.toString('hex', 0, 4);
      if (
        magigNumberInBody == magic.jpg ||
        magigNumberInBody == magic.png ||
        magigNumberInBody == magic.gif
      ) {
        responseBody.push(data);
      } else {
        //The data must be text/plain
        var body = data.toString().split('\r\n');
        // parsing items
        body.forEach(function(item) {
          if (
            item.startsWith('Events[0]')
          {
            var propertyAndValue = item.split('=');
            var attribute = propertyAndValue[0].split('.').pop();
            var value = propertyAndValue[1];
            setKeypath(items, attribute, value); //Set key and value to object items
          }
        });
      }
      // How can I detect end of image?
      if (Object.keys(items).length !== 0) {
          responseBody = Buffer.concat(responseBody); //Concat the image data

        items.image = responseBody; //Add the image into item objects
        console.log('items : ' + items);
        self.emit('detect', items); //Emit items object to client
      } else {
        self.emit('detect', { status: 'Unable To Detect' });
      }
    })
```

Comment: Your example includes a `Content-Type`, why are you looking at magic numbers instead of the content type? Also you should consider using the `Content-Length`

Comment: Because I want to detect whether it is image/jpeg or text/plain. So, I need to detect if it starts with magic numbers. I see... How can I parse the response based on the content-length? Basically there are two content-types in the response. One is for text/plain. Another one is image/jpeg